# communication gz->ROS2 doesn't work, how to debug?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have a pb with ros_gz_bridge, I use ROS2-Humble, Gazebo-Garden, get **ros_gz from source**, branche humble and after compilation (and source my env in each shell) in a new workspace I tried exemple from ros_gz_bridge. (changing *ignition* for *gz* in commands)

- Example 1a: communication gz -> ROS2
  => KO nothing is received in ROS2 topic
- Example 1b: communication ROS2
  -> gz => OK

I can't understand what's going wrong.

```
# shell A
$ ros2 run ros_gz_bridge parameter_bridge /chatter@std_msgs/msg/String@gz.msgs.StringMsg
[INFO] [1683186627.556779317] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/chatter (gz.msgs.StringMsg) -> /chatter (std_msgs/msg/String)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1683186627.558527086] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/chatter (std_msgs/msg/String) -> /chatter (gz.msgs.StringMsg)] (Lazy 0)

# shell B
$ ros2 topic echo /chatter
# nothing

# shell C
$ gz topic -t /chatter -m gz.msgs.StringMsg -p 'data:"Hello"'

# shell D (to control msg is really sent)
$ gz topic --echo -t /chatter
data: "Hello"
```

As far as I understand, it is probably a pb with message type.

```
$ ros2 topic type /chatter
std_msgs/msg/String

$ gz topic -t /chatter --info
Publishers [Address, Message Type]:
  tcp://192.168.21.112:37511, ignition.msgs.StringMsg
```

This ignition message is suspicious to me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414988/communication-gz-%3Eros2-doesn%27t-work,-how-to-debug-?/) by [SébastienL](https://answers.ros.org/users/146607/s%C3%A9bastienl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2023-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok got it from https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/issues/365

I have to `export GZ_VERSION=garden` before compiling.

```
$ gz topic --info -t /chatter
Publishers [Address, Message Type]:
  tcp://127.0.0.1:39363, gz.msgs.StringMsg
```

---

Originally posted by [SébastienL](https://answers.ros.org/users/146607/s%C3%A9bastienl/) with karma: 32 on 2023-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0